# Knockout JS - Issues binding data to my table

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

HI folks I am quite new with knockout and learning as I go. I managed to recreate what im trying to accomplish on my site via jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/N2zNk/49/. I copied the code and put it into my site, the only difference is that I am getting data from the server via AJAX.

What happens now is that my tables manages to create 1 row in my table with my edit button but is not rendering any of my text bindings. I believe that something with the Ajax is what`s causing me the issues but can't figure out what it is.

Would anyone have any clue?

Console error message:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "text: function (){return Incident }"
Message: Incident is not defined
```

HTML code:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover text-center" id="example2">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="30" class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-list-alt fa-4"></i></th>
            <th width="75" class="text-center"> Incident <i class="fa fa-ticket"></i> </th>
            <th width="65" class="text-center"> Priorité <i class="fa fa-balance-scale"></i> </th>
            <th width="70" class="text-center"> Composante <i class="fa fa-building-o"></i> </th>
            <th width="300" class="text-center"> Description <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i> </th>
            <th width="100" class="text-center"> Date de début <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> </th>
            <th width="100" class="text-center"> Responsable <i class="fa fa-user"></i> </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'Incidents', foreach: dataFromServer() }" />
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My template code:

```
<script type="text/html" id="Incidents">
<tr>
    <td class='over_flow_control'><button class='edit_button btn btn-default btn-sm' type='button' value='Edit' data-bind="click: $parent.editProduct"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></i></button></td>
    <td class='over_flow_control' data-bind="text: Incident"></td>
    <td class='over_flow_control'><h4><span class='priorité_span' data-bind="text:PrioritéValue"></span></h4></td>
    <td class='over_flow_control' data-bind="text:Composante"></td>
    <td class='over_flow_control text-left' data-bind="text:Description"></td>
    <td class='over_flow_control Date_de_début_cell' data-bind="text:Date_de_début"></td>
    <td class='over_flow_control' data-bind="text:ResponsableValue"></td>    
</tr>
</script>
```

My javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function load_incidents(ID, Description, Composante, Incident, ÉtatValue, PrioritéValue, Duré, Date_de_début, Date_de_fin, Groupe_Support_Prime, Autres_Groupe_Support_Prime, ResponsableValue, Impact, Temps_Consacré, Type_de_tempsValue, Journal_des_actions, Dépanage, Suivi, Ressources) {
    var self = this;
    this.ID = ID;
    this.Description = ko.observable(Description);
    this.Composante = ko.observable(Composante);
    this.Incident = ko.observable(Incident);
    this.ÉtatValue = ko.observable(ÉtatValue);
    this.PrioritéValue = ko.observable(PrioritéValue);
    this.Duré = ko.observable(Duré);
    this.Date_de_début = ko.observable(Date_de_début);
    this.Date_de_fin = ko.observable(Date_de_fin);
    this.Groupe_Support_Prime = ko.observable(Groupe_Support_Prime);
    this.Autres_Groupe_Support_Prime = ko.observable(Autres_Groupe_Support_Prime);
    this.ResponsableValue = ko.observable(ResponsableValue);
    this.Impact = ko.observable(Impact);
    this.Temps_Consacré = ko.observable(Temps_Consacré);
    this.Type_de_tempsValue = ko.observable(Type_de_tempsValue);
    this.Journal_des_actions = ko.observable(Journal_des_actions);
    this.Dépanage = ko.observable(Dépanage);
    this.Journal_des_actions = ko.observable(Journal_des_actions);
    this.Suivi = ko.observable(Suivi);
    this.Ressources = ko.observable(Ressources);

    //This is the start edit group//
    this.editDescription = ko.observable(Description);
    this.editComposante = ko.observable(Composante);
    this.editIncident = ko.observable(Incident);
    this.editÉtatValue = ko.observable(ÉtatValue);
    this.editPrioritéValue = ko.observable(PrioritéValue);
    this.editDuré = ko.observable(Duré);
    this.editDate_de_début = ko.observable(Date_de_début);
    this.editDate_de_fin = ko.observable(Date_de_fin);
    this.editGroupe_Support_Prime = ko.observable(Groupe_Support_Prime);
    this.editAutres_Groupe_Support_Prime = ko.observable(Autres_Groupe_Support_Prime);
    this.editResponsableValue = ko.observable(ResponsableValue);
    this.editImpact = ko.observable(Impact);
    this.editTemps_Consacré = ko.observable(Temps_Consacré);
    this.editType_de_tempsValue = ko.observable(Type_de_tempsValue);
    this.editJournal_des_actions = ko.observable(Journal_des_actions);
    this.editDépanage = ko.observable(Dépanage);
    this.editJournal_des_actions = ko.observable(Journal_des_actions);
    this.editSuivi = ko.observable(Suivi);
    this.editRessources = ko.observable(Ressources);

    //end of the edit group//
    this.accept = function () {
    this.Description(this.editDescription());
    this.Composante(this.editComposante());
    this.Incident(this.editIncident());
    this.ÉtatValue(this.editÉtatValue());
    this.PrioritéValue(this.editPrioritéValue());
    this.Duré(this.editDuré());
    this.Date_de_début(this.editDate_de_début());
    this.Date_de_fin(this.editDate_de_fin());
    this.Groupe_Support_Prime(this.editGroupe_Support_Prime);
    this.Autres_Groupe_Support_Prime(this.editAutres_Groupe_Support_Prime());
    this.ResponsableValue(this.editResponsableValue());
    this.Impact(this.editImpact());
    this.Temps_Consacré(this.editTemps_Consacré());
    this.Type_de_tempsValue(this.editType_de_tempsValue());
    this.Journal_des_actions(this.editJournal_des_actions());
    this.Dépanage(this.editDépanage());
    this.Journal_des_actions(this.editJournal_des_actions());
    this.Suivi(this.editSuivi());
    this.Ressources(this.editRessources());
    return true;
    }.bind(this);

    //reset to originals on cancel
    this.cancel = function () {
    this.editDescription(this.Description());
    this.editComposante(this.Composante());
    this.editIncident(this.Incident());
    this.editÉtatValue(this.ÉtatValue());
    this.editPrioritéValue(this.PrioritéValue());
    this.editDuré(this.Duré());
    this.editDate_de_début(this.Date_de_début());
    this.editDate_de_fin(this.Date_de_fin());
    this.editGroupe_Support_Prime(this.Groupe_Support_Prime);
    this.editAutres_Groupe_Support_Prime(this.Autres_Groupe_Support_Prime());
    this.editResponsableValue(this.ResponsableValue());
    this.editImpact(this.Impact());
    this.editTemps_Consacré(this.Temps_Consacré());
    this.editType_de_tempsValue(this.Type_de_tempsValue());
    this.editJournal_des_actions(this.Journal_des_actions());
    this.editDépanage(this.Dépanage());
    this.editJournal_des_actions(this.Journal_des_actions());
    this.editSuivi(this.Suivi());
    this.editRessources(this.Ressources());
    }.bind(this);
}

Incidents = {
pvm: {},
productStore: {
    products: [],
    init: function (data) {
        this.products = $.map(data, function (product) {
            return new load_incidents(product.ID, product.Description(), product.Composante());
        });
        console.log(this.products);
    }
},  

init: function () {

var self = this;
dataFromServer = ko.observableArray([]);
$.getJSON("../../../../_vti_bin/listData.svc/GDI_PROD_Incidents?$filter=ÉtatValue%20ne%20%27Fermé%27&$orderby=PrioritéValue desc",
function (data) {
if (data.d.results) {
dataFromServer(JSON.stringify(data.d.results));
console.log(dataFromServer());
}
}
);
Incidents.productStore.init(dataFromServer());
},
productViewModel: function (data) {
        var self = this;
        var productsArray = [];

            productsArray = data;

        this.products = ko.observableArray(productsArray);
        this.selectedProduct = ko.observable();
        this.editProduct = function (productToEdit) {
            self.selectedProduct(productToEdit);

            // Incidents.pvm.selectedProduct(productToEdit);
        };
        this.acceptEdit = function () {
            var selected = Incidents.pvm.selectedProduct();
            if (selected.accept()) {
                Incidents.pvm.selectedProduct("");
                $('#dialogEditProduct').popup('close');
            }
        };
        this.cancelEdit = function () {
            Incidents.pvm.selectedProduct().cancel();
            Incidents.pvm.selectedProduct("");
            $('#dialogEditProduct').popup('close');
        };
    }
};
ko.bindingHandlers.jqButton = {
    init: function (element) {
        $(element).button();
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var currentValue = valueAccessor();
        $(element).button("option", "disabled", currentValue.enable === false);
    }
};

ko.bindingHandlers.openProductDialog = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {  
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        if (value) {
            $.mobile.changePage("#dialogEditProduct", {
                role: 'dialog'
            });
            $("#dialogEditProduct").open();    
            // $("#dialogEditProduct").trigger('create');    
        }

    }
};

$.extend({
    isNumber: function (obj) {
        return !isNaN(parseFloat(obj)) && isFinite(obj);
    }
});

Incidents.init(); 
ko.applyBindings(Incidents);
</script>
```

Comment: Also at the bottom of my script I had added ko.applyBindings(Incidents); which wasent in my jsfiddle. Without it my table dosent load at all.

Comment: You shpuld improve your answer by reducing the sample code, to the minimum necessary to understand the problem. You should also include the jsfiddel code in your question. Believe me, to explain the problem you can show a viewmodel with one or two properties. In this way it's easier to understand, and you'll get more chances to get a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like most of the problem is that you are not using correctly the `var self=this` pattern.

An usual JavaScript constructor looks like this:

```
var MyVm = function() {
  this.name = ko.observable('John');
  this.age = ko.observable(23);
}
```

Then you call it like this:

```
var myVm = new MyVm();
```

This pattern becomes to get complicated when you start adding functions, because you must be careful with how this is bound.

```
var MyVm = function() {
  this.name = ko.observable('John');
  this.age = ko.observable(23);
  this.incAge = function() {
    this.age(this.age()+1);
  };
}
```

Depending on how you do it, when you call `incAge` it may not work as expected because `this` can be something different to your view model. That's why the `var self = this;` pattern exists. But it's used like this:

```
var MyVm = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.name = ko.observable('John');
  self.age = ko.observable(23);
  self.incAge = function() {
    self.age(self.age()+1);
  };
  return self;
}
```

With this pattern you don'ty have to worry about how you invoke `incAge`.

You've pasted too much code, so it's hard to see the exact problem. *You should read this carefully: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which will also help you solving your own problems*. Even so, I can see that you're not using the pattern correctly. Start using it as shown in my example, and don't forget the indispensable `return self;`. In your case you're using a constructor with parameters, which would be something like this:

```
var MyVm = function(_name, _age) {
  var self = this;
  self.name = ko.observable(_name);
  self.age = ko.observable(_age);
  self.incAge = function() {
    self.age(self.age()+1);
  };
  return self;
}
```

To finish my answer, I can see that you're mapping most properties directly into observables with the same name. You can spare a lot of time and code by using [knockout mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html).

Comment: Thank you very much JotaBe!

Answer (score 1):

As an example of the this pattern, I show you de delete link.  It don't work in your fiddle.

You have to change your html first:

```
    <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removeItem">Delete</a>
```

and then add the removeItem() function to  your ViewModel:

```
productViewModel: function (data) {
    var self = this;
    var productsArray = [];
    if (data && data.length > 0) {
        productsArray = data;
    }
    self.products = ko.observableArray(productsArray);

    this.selectedProduct = ko.observable();

    this.removeItem = function (productToRemove){
        self.products.remove(productToRemove);
    }
```

If you try to execute this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/whudg30v/1/) you can see that deletes rows.

If you change this line:

```
                self.products.remove(productToRemove);
```

with this one:

```
                this.products.remove(productToRemove);
```

(the only change is **this** for **self**), it don't work.

The Knockout tutorial about [lists](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=collections) can be very helpful to you.